# How can I prevents touches from passing through a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Here's the setup:

1. UIScrollView: (0, 0, 320, 568)
2. UIImageView:  (0, 0, 320, 568) on top of UIScrollView

The problem is that when the UIImageView is visible and the user touches it the touches
pass through the UIImageView to the UIScrollView and it scrolls.

How can I prevents touches from passing through the UIImageView?

Comment: Isn't the objective of the scroll view behind ImageView is to scroll the image? can you elaborate more.

Comment: as @bllakjakk sais it's important more info. But If your imageView is inside the scrollView in the top, you should be sure that it has imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; and it has a gestureRecognizer attached or override the methods to handle touches.

Comment: What do you want to happen when he user touches the UIImageView?

Comment: When the user touches the UIImageView I want nothing to happen. I don't want the UIScrollView to scroll. When the UIImageView has an image this whole thing is deactivated. I don't want it to scroll accidentally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An image view has user interaction disabled by default, so when the system is figuring out which view should receive a touch, it ignores the image view.

Turn on user interaction for the image view.  In code, set its `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES`.  In a xib or storyboard, find the checkbox in the attributes inspector and turn it on.